# error in list view

Tags: java, android

hi i created an app. In that when i hit a button it moves over to a new page, the page contains a list of item. The layout has been fixed as if a list view with a scroll view. Once i scroll the page is been changed over to a black screen. Is  is this the problem in my coding or it is common to all apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below line to your ListView in xml

```
android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
```